# how to configure TIdHttp with TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL to use certificates of type USB key

Tags: delphi, https, ssl-certificate, indy

Good morning,

I wonder how to configure TIdHttp with TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL to use certificates of type USB key, because it is only possible using key file type.

This key is an Alladin, and I wish I could select the key to be used as various certificate if any certificate keys.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenSSL does not natively support using USB keys.  Although OpenSSL does have APIs for loading certificate data from memory, Indy does not expose that functionality yet.  So at this time, you can only load certificate files from disk.  If the USB key has a drive letter assigned to it, and contains certificate files in PEM or ASN.1 format, you can try pointing Indy directly to the USB key's files, otherwise you are basically SOL.

Comment: Remy the savior christ! thanks again and again Remy... I load it into the memory!